# PHPExcel library hangs with relative "big" files

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm trying to export some records to excel from my MySQL (webserver) and when the query returns >4k records the script hangs the web browser and temporaly the web hosting.

My `PHP_version` is 5.2.13-pl1-gentoo and the `memory_limit` configurated in `php.ini` is 128M

The result excel only have one column and N rows. With 100 or 200 rows the php script runs fine.

This is the php script

```
<? session_start();
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
set_time_limit(0);
include("include/conexion.php");    
require_once 'include/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'include/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Name")
->setLastModifiedBy("Name")
->setTitle("Listado")
->setSubject("Listado")
->setDescription("Listado.")
->setKeywords("Listado")
->setCategory("Listado");


    $query = explode("|",stripcslashes($_POST['query']));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List');

  $resEmp = mysql_query ($query, $conexion ) or die(mysql_error());
  $tot = mysql_num_rows($resEmp);
  $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($resEmp);

  $fistIndex = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 1)->getColumn();
  $lastIndex = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($num_campos - 1, 1)->getColumn();


  //tittles
  for ($e=0;$e < $num_fields;$e++){     
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($e, 2, utf8_decode(ucwords(mysql_field_name($resEmp,$e))));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($e, 2)->getColumn())->setAutoSize(true);
  }
  //color tittles
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle( $fistIndex.'1:'.$lastIndex.'2' )->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('c5c5c7');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle( $fistIndex.'1:'.$lastIndex.'2' )->getFont()->setBold(true);


    if(isset ( $_POST ['mail'] )){

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 2, "Email");
    $emails = array();
    for ($row = 0; $row < $totEmp; $row++) {
        //more than one mail in field separated by ";"
        $aux = explode(";", mysql_result($resEmp,$row,$col));

        for($i=0; $i<count($aux); $i++){

            $cleaned = utf8_encode(strtolower(trim($aux[$i])));
            //filter repeated mails
            if(!in_array($cleaned, $emails) && $aux[$i] != ""){ 
                $num_rows = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($num_rows + 1, 1);
                array_push($emails, $cleaned);                  
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $num_rows + 1, $cleaned);
            }

        }

    }

  }


  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

  header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$nom_archivo.".xlsx");

  // Write file to the browser
  $objWriter->save('php://output');
  exit();


?>
```

When enter to the script run a mysql query and then, iterate the result to get the mail field, if the obtained mail not exist in a array this mail is inserted in excel

I've tried to set

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
set_time_limit(0);
```

But the problem persist.

Any idea to solve problem?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT 1**

I've updated the code with the recommendations and now works fine. 
Anyway How can I get if occurs any error or the memory usage just before of hanging?
How can I get the max memory_limit available to set with `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` ?

```
 <? session_start();
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
    set_time_limit(0);
    include("include/conexion.php");    
    require_once 'include/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'include/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Name")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("Name")
    ->setTitle("Listado")
    ->setSubject("Listado")
    ->setDescription("Listado.")
    ->setKeywords("Listado")
    ->setCategory("Listado");

    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $query = explode("|",stripcslashes($_POST['query']));
    $activeSheet->setTitle('List');

      $resEmp = mysql_query ($query, $conexion ) or die(mysql_error());
      $tot = mysql_num_rows($resEmp);
      $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($resEmp);

      $fistIndex = $activeSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 1)->getColumn();
      $lastIndex = $activeSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($num_campos - 1, 1)->getColumn();


      //tittles
      for ($e=0;$e < $num_fields;$e++){     
        $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($e, 2, utf8_decode(ucwords(mysql_field_name($resEmp,$e))));
        $activeSheet->getColumnDimension($activeSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($e, 2)->getColumn())->setAutoSize(true);
      }
      //color tittles
      $activeSheet->getStyle( $fistIndex.'1:'.$lastIndex.'2' )->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('c5c5c7');
      $activeSheet->getStyle( $fistIndex.'1:'.$lastIndex.'2' )->getFont()->setBold(true);


        if(isset ( $_POST ['mail'] )){

        $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 2, "Email");
        $emails = array();
        for ($row = 0; $row < $totEmp; $row++) {
            //more than one mail in field separated by ";"
            $aux = explode(";", mysql_result($resEmp,$row,$col));

            for($i=0; $i<count($aux); $i++){

                $cleaned = utf8_encode(strtolower(trim($aux[$i])));
                //filter repeated mails
                if(!in_array($cleaned, $emails) && $aux[$i] != ""){ 
                    array_push($emails, $cleaned);                                      
                }

            }

        }
    for ($row = 0; $row < count($emails); $row++) {
        $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row + 3, $emails[$row]);
    }

      }


      $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

      header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$nom_archivo.".xlsx");

      // Write file to the browser
      $objWriter->save('php://output');
      exit();


    ?>
```

Comment: We use PHP Excel on our platform, and we ended up limiting users to less than ~5k rows of export, as the processing time was too large and memory requirements too. Does your query run in reasonable time? Also you shouldn't really be sending the query directly from the POST request, you should send parameters and then escape their output to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I've tested the execution time of the complete algorithm only without the excel write and the time is of 0.2s for 3500 records of one column. I think 3000 is far too few rows for hanging up. I think there must be another problem

Comment: One issue: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($num_rows + 1, 1);` get rid of this.... it's an expensive call, and not necessary for your worksheet because you're building it from new, not inserting into the middle of an existing worksheet

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<count($aux); $i++){` Why not simply use a `foreach()` loop?

Comment: I've updated with the recommendations and some new questions, thanks for answer again

Answer (score 0):

Seems this library has serious problem in parsing large excel spreadsheets, I'd this issue already & I couldn't find a proper solution. I guess this is normal behaviour because this library is written fully in PHP that causes a lot of parsing overhead.
I strongly suggest you to use a excel parsing PHP-extension like [this one](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel).
As another thinkable solution [if its possible], you can break down your big file to several smaller files (e.g by sheets), otherwise I guess you should use a faster CPU or use another library or programming language to parse your exel files (e.g. [apache-poi](https://poi.apache.org/) in java, maybe with a [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/how_it_works.php)).

Comment: I've tested the execution time of the complete algorithm only without the excel write computation and the time is of 0.2s for 3500 records of one column. I think 3000 is far too few rows for hanging up. I think there must be another problem. To write excels, Do I have to do $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp; $cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '512MB'); PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings);?

Comment: I've updated with the recommendations and some new questions, thanks for answer again

Comment: Another alternative is Spout: https://github.com/box/spout. It's a PHP library (so no need to recompile PHP) and is free! I used it to create and read XLSX files with millions of rows. No need to increase memory or time limit, it just works!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PHPExcel is not good for performing with large data because PHP is not really a good binary file processing language.

Some people export their data to XML format of excel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) and it can work well. However, the xml format does not have full features of excel binary file and of course it will have a bigger file size.

In order to work with the large data (import/export to binary excel file), our system now using libxl which will cost you 199$ for a license, and php_excel which is a wrapper for libxl. In effect, our system now export a excel file with more than 5k of rows in about just only some seconds using libxl and I think it's an only solution for you until now to use binary excel.

P/s: The $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() also have a cost, so you could store it value to a variable for reusing later which will help you to speed up your code a little bit.

Comment: I've tested the execution time of the complete algorithm only without the excel write computation and the time is of 0.2s for 3500 records of one column. I think 3000 is far too few rows for hanging up. I think there must be another problem. To write excels,  Do I have to do `$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;`   
`$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '512MB');`    
`PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings);`?

Comment: You could store $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() in a variable to reuse later because it also have a cost

Comment: I've updated with the recommendations and some new questions, thanks for answer again

Comment: @TruongHua, you should check out [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout). It is faster than libXL, only requires 10MB of memory to process XLSX files of any size; and it's free !!

Comment: @Adrien I have not using Spout already. However, at first glance, I see that Spout may create XML format of excel file instead of binary excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but after changed some options in php.ini and scripts, I could reduce file from 28 MB to 4 MB.

1. increase `memory_limit=2048M` in php.ini.
2. change `max_execution_time` to more seconds.
3. in the script yo should use Excel2007 like below:

   ob_end_clean();

   ```
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$date.xls");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    ob_end_clean();

    $objWriter =PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
   ```